E-ra IOT platform
Does anyone know about E-ra IOT platform? I have carried out my small project on it. I have a trouble with my data. I wonder why my hourly flow rate does not reset in every hours? It still stayed at 14.9 L. 14.9L is hourly flow rate at 0h00. I thought that the hourly flow rate should reset every hour and display on the chart. Unfortunately, it doesn't show hourly flow rate on the chart either since at the midnight. I'm using esp32s, ds3231,YF-B1,... Please review my code, I don't know where I was wrong.
#define ERA_DEBUG
#define DEFAULT_MQTT_HOST "**********"
#define ERA_AUTH_TOKEN "****************"

#define FLOW_SENSOR_PIN 25
#define CALIBRATION_FACTOR 4.5
#define RAIN_SENSOR_PIN 36
#define RAIN_THRESHOLD_RAW 2000

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ERa.hpp>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <ArtronShop_SHT3x.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <RTClib.h>

const char* myphone = "********";

volatile int flowPulseCount = 0;
float flowRate = 0.0;
float totalFlow = 0.0;
unsigned long lastFlowTime = 0;

int rainSensorValue = 0;
bool isRaining = false;

unsigned long lastHourTime = 0;
float previousTotalFlow = 0.0;
float hourlyFlow = 0.0;

unsigned long lastDayTime = 0;
float previousDailyFlow = 0.0;
float dailyFlow = 0.0;

const char ssid[] = "**********";
const char pass[] = "********";

RTC_DS3231 rtc;
ArtronShop_SHT3x sht3x(0x44, &Wire);
WiFiClient mbTcpClient;

void flowPulseCounter() {
    flowPulseCount++;
}


void readEEPROM() {
    totalFlow = EEPROM.readFloat(0);
    previousTotalFlow = totalFlow;
}

void writeEEPROM(float value) {
    EEPROM.writeFloat(0, value);
    EEPROM.commit();
}

void handleRainSensor() {
    rainSensorValue = analogRead(RAIN_SENSOR_PIN);
    Serial.print("Rain Sensor Value: ");
    Serial.println(rainSensorValue);

    if (rainSensorValue > RAIN_THRESHOLD_RAW) {
        if (!isRaining) {
            Serial.println("Rain detected!");
            ERa.virtualWrite(V6, 1);
            isRaining = true;
        }
    } else {
        if (isRaining) {
            Serial.println("No rain detected.");
            ERa.virtualWrite(V6, 0);
            isRaining = false;
        }
    }
}

void calculateFlow() {
    if (millis() - lastFlowTime >= 1000) {
        flowRate = (flowPulseCount / CALIBRATION_FACTOR);
        flowPulseCount = 0;
        totalFlow += (flowRate / 60.0);
        writeEEPROM(totalFlow);

        Serial.print("Flow Rate: ");
        Serial.print(flowRate, 2);
        Serial.print(" L/min\tTotal Flow: ");
        Serial.print(totalFlow, 2);
        Serial.println(" L");

        ERa.virtualWrite(V4, flowRate);
        ERa.virtualWrite(V5, totalFlow);
        lastFlowTime = millis();
    }
}

void handleHourlyFlow() {
    if (millis() - lastHourTime >= 3600000UL) {
        hourlyFlow = totalFlow - previousTotalFlow;
        ERa.virtualWrite(V7, hourlyFlow);
        Serial.print("Hourly Flow: ");
        Serial.print(hourlyFlow, 2);
        Serial.println(" L");

        previousTotalFlow = totalFlow;
        lastHourTime = millis();
    }
}

void handleDailyFlow() {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    if (now.hour() == 0 && now.minute() == 0 && now.second() == 0) {
        dailyFlow = totalFlow;
        ERa.virtualWrite(V8, dailyFlow);
        Serial.print("Daily Flow Reset: ");
        Serial.print(dailyFlow, 2);
        Serial.println(" L");

        totalFlow = 0.0;
        writeEEPROM(totalFlow);
        previousDailyFlow = dailyFlow;
        lastDayTime = millis();

        if (hourlyFlow >= 14.9) {
            Serial.println("Luu Luong Vuot qua quy dinh");
            sendSMS(myphone,"Luu Luong vuot qua quy dinh");
        }
    }
}

void timerEvent() {
    if (sht3x.measure()) {
        Serial.print("Temperature: ");
        Serial.print(sht3x.temperature(), 1);
        ERa.virtualWrite(V2, sht3x.temperature());
        ERa.virtualWrite(V3, sht3x.humidity());
        Serial.print(" *C\tHumidity: ");
        Serial.print(sht3x.humidity(), 1);
        Serial.print(" %RH");
        Serial.println();
    }
    ERA_LOG(ERA_PSTR("Timer"), ERA_PSTR("Uptime: %d"), ERaMillis() / 1000L);

    calculateFlow();
    handleRainSensor();
    handleHourlyFlow();
    handleDailyFlow();
}

void setup() {
    #if defined(ERA_DEBUG)
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial2.begin(115200); // Tốc độ baud của module SIM
    #endif

    ERa.setModbusClient(mbTcpClient);
    ERa.setScanWiFi(true);
    ERa.begin(ssid, pass);
    EEPROM.begin(512);
    readEEPROM();

    pinMode(FLOW_SENSOR_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(RAIN_SENSOR_PIN, INPUT);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(FLOW_SENSOR_PIN), flowPulseCounter, FALLING);
    Serial2.println("AT");
    delay(100);
    if (Serial2.available()) {
      Serial.println("Module SIM kết nối thành công!");
    } else {
      Serial.println("Không thể kết nối với module SIM.");
    }
    sendSMS(myphone, "Thiet Bi Da Khoi Dong!");

    Wire.begin();
    while (!sht3x.begin()) {
        Serial.println("SHT3x not found !");
        delay(1000);
    }

    if (!rtc.begin()) {
        Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
        while (1);
    }

    if (rtc.lostPower()) {
        Serial.println("RTC lost power, setting the time!");
        rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
    }

    ERa.addInterval(1000L, timerEvent);
    lastHourTime = millis();
    lastDayTime = millis();
}

void loop() {
    ERa.run ();
}


void sendSMS(const char* phoneNumber, const char* message) {
    Serial2.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Chuyển sang chế độ nhắn tin văn bản
    delay(100);
    Serial2.print("AT+CMGS=\"");
    Serial2.print(phoneNumber);
    Serial2.println("\""); // Số điện thoại nhận
    delay(100);
    Serial2.print(message); // Nội dung tin nhắn
    delay(100);
    Serial2.write(0x1A); // Ký tự kết thúc tin nhắn
    delay(100);
}

void call(const char* phoneNumber) {
    Serial2.print("ATD");
    Serial2.print(phoneNumber);
    Serial2.println(";"); // Thực hiện cuộc gọi
    delay(100);
}

void endCall() {
    Serial2.println("ATH"); // Kết thúc cuộc gọi
    delay(100);
}


enter image description here
well, at first, i thought that maybe because my flow rate is not big enough to affect the hourly flow rate so the hourly flow rate still the same. But i recognize, if this case happens, the chart will show the same hourly flow rate in every hours but it didnt. The chart only shows the hourly flow rate at midnight.

You need RTC hardware for something like this. A regular MCU crystal won't be accurate enough, let along some built-in one.

Well, i use RTC module DS3231 as i said on the post but it didnt work tho

You seem to be using millis() which would be based on the MCU clock.
